# How do i exclude a certain group from a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have grouped the data together but I do not know how to exclude certain groups of data from a CSV file.

Here is my code: `data2 = df.groupby(['cor','moa']).sum()`

In this CSV file, cor means the country that visitors stay at, so this column consists of groups like total and asean which I would like to exclude. However, I do not know how to go about doing so.

Comment: Show some relevant data so that we better understand what you really require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can do:

```
data2 = df[df['cor'] != 'asean'].groupby(['cor','moa']).sum()
```